# OutlinedBox de TextInputLayout no funciona

Tags: android, material-design

> No establece el estilo correctamente

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Host">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

> El hint queda debajo del recuadro y no deberia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El problema era que yo estoy utilizando api 29.0.2 entonces tenia que agregar esta version en mi gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

> Si utilizas las 28.0 puede ser que te sirva la:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```